# $\int_c \frac{8-z}{z(4-z)} dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to calculate the following contour integral: $$\int_c \frac{8-z}{z(4-z)} dz$$ where $C$ is the circle of radius $7$, center $0$, negatively oriented.

---

Do I have to do this the long and tedious way or is there a nicer short cut?

---

This has a pole at $0$ and $4$, so I need to calculate the residues for these two and take the line integral across the paramterisation of a circle moving clockwise of radius $7$, centered at the origin, that's all there is to it right?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [***residue theorem***](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ResidueTheorem.html) to have:

$$ I = 2 \pi \mathrm{i} \left( \mathrm{Res}(f)_{z=0} + \mathrm{Res}(f)_{z=4}  \right) =  2 \pi \mathrm{i} \left( 2 -1\right) = 2\pi \mathrm{i} $$

Cheers!

Comment: he specifies that $C$ is negatively oriented, so I think the answer should be $-2\pi i$